# Publishing sequences/objects through RTI Conector to ROS2 applications

Tags: python, ros, data-distribution-service, ros2, rti-dds

I am interfacing ROS2 with a native RTI DDS Connector for Python where I am publishing messages in RTI connector and subscribing in ROS2.

I have the following message structure for the message named `DetectedObjectList`:

```
int16 id
// An array of objects of another message type
DetectedObject[ ] objects
```

This is interpreted as unbounded sequences in IDL.

Another message named `DetectedObject`:

```
int16 id
string name
int16 x
int16 y
```

Let's say the topic used for communication is "**objects**" and the message type is "**DetectedObjectList**".

Since the subscriber in ROS2 is subscribing to **id of type int16 and objects of type DetectedObject[]**, how can I publish an object from RTI connector?

The usual flow in RTI Connector is:

- Get an instance of the output:

  `output = connector.getOutput("MyPublisher::MyDataWriter")`
- Post an instance:

  `output.instance.setNumber("id", 5)`

  `output.write()`

How can I write an object of type `DetectedObject` instead of `setNumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with ROS, but I'll try to help with the DDS/Connector part.

As far as I know in DDS you cannot specify an unbounded array. You can have unbounded Sequences, but not arrays. So, if you are using a type that looks like this:

```
struct DetectedObject {
  short id;
  string name;
  short x;
  short y;
};


struct MyMessage {
  short id;
  DetectedObject objects[10];
};
```

or you have an unbounded sequence instead:

```
struct DetectedObject {
  short id;
  string name;
  short x;
  short y;
};


struct MyMessage {
  short id;
  sequence<DetectedObject> objects;
};
```

Then your connector code will be something like this:

```
connector = rti.Connector("MyParticipantLibrary::PubParticipant",
                          filepath + "/ROS.xml")
outputDDS = connector.getOutput("MyPub::MyTopicWriter")

for i in range(1, 500):
    # There are two ways to set values in an instance:

    # 1. Field by Fields:
    outputDDS.instance.setNumber("id", 1)
        #note index, for now, starts from 1. This may change in the future
    outputDDS.instance.setNumber("objects[1].id", 2)
    outputDDS.instance.setString("objects[1].name", "aName")
    outputDDS.instance.setNumber("objects[1].x", 3)
    outputDDS.instance.setNumber("objects[1].y", 4)
    outputDDS.write()

        # OR

    # 2. By first creating a dictionary and then setting it all at once:
    myDict = {'id': 5, 'objects': [{'id': 6, 'name': '', 'x': 7, 'y': 8}]}
    outputDDS.instance.setDictionary(myDict)
    outputDDS.write()
    sleep(2)
```

Maybe somebody else can contribute more about the ROS <--> DDS mapping when it comes to unbounded arrays.

I hope this help, 
  Gianpiero